# Meta-regression with highly-correlated predictors? Should I do 2 analyses? Example in R

Tags: r, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I'm trying to do meta-regression with a lot of trials (>40 trials with >100 'arms') investigating the efficacy of a procedure (abl) and any 'addon' procedure. Each trial will have 2 or more arms. In some trials, the 'control' arm is no procedure; in others is a 'vanilla' procedure, with the active arm adding in various 'extras'.

I want to see not only if the procedure improves outcomes, but also if various 'extras' to the procedure also influence outcome.

My columns which are predictors in my model start with 'pred_'. If they are to do with the procedure used (abl), they start 'pred_abl_'

```
> head(af_dat)
        id arm  xi  ni pred_age pred_gender pred_antiarrhythmics pred_abl_pvi_done pred_abl_pvi_type pred_abl_cryo pred_abl_cfea pred_abl_gp pred_abl_lines pred_abl_mapping                      pred_endpoint pred_at_included pred_blanking        pi
1 23094720   A 112 146     56.0        68.0                    0                 1                 1             0             0           0              1                1                             Holter                0             3 0.7671233
2 23094720   B 103 148     54.0        72.0                    1                 0                 0             0             0           0              0                0                             Holter                0             3 0.6959459
3 21539635   A  45  58     57.6        66.0                    0                 1                 1             0             1           0              0                1                            Holter                 1             3 0.7758621
4 21539635   B  14  24     56.4        67.0                    0                 0                 0             0             1           0              0                1                             Holter                1             3 0.5833333
5 21539635   C  27  35     52.2        71.0                    0                 1                 1             0             0           0              0                1                             Holter                1             3 0.7714286
6 24549549   A  50  66     56.3        77.3                    0                 1                 1             0             0           0              0                0 Mobile telemetry (transtelephonic)                1             3 0.7575758
```

The column which indicates if they had a procedure at all is pred_abl_pvi_done. The other columns beginning pred_abl_* (of which there are 6 shown above) describe the presence of any 'extras' to the procedure, and **must** be 0 if the pred_abl_pvi_done is 0, by definition.

Initially, I was going to do the meta-regression as follows:

```
rma(measure='PLO', xi=xi, ni=ni, data=af_dat, mods=~pred_age+pred_gender+pred_antiarrhythmics+pred_abl_pvi_done+pred_abl_pvi_type+pred_abl_cryo+pred_abl_cfea+pred_abl_gp+pred_abl_lines+pred_abl_mapping+pred_endpoint+pred_at_included+pred_blanking)
```

However, I'm not sure if this is valid; the pred_abl_* columns will of course be very strongly correlated with pred_abl_pvi_done as they will be 0 if the latter is 0. If the 'abl' procedure (pred_abl_pvi_done=1) is very efficacious, I'm worried the other pred_abl_* columns will also appear correlated even if they add nothing prognostically, as many of the '0's for these columns will merely be indicating no procedure has been done at all.

One way to get around this, I suppose, would be to only look at the 6 procedural columns if pred_abl_pvi_done is 1.

I could therefore do 2 analysies:

1. Multivariate regression of all the studies, excluding the 6 procedural columns. I would then see if a procedure versus no procedure (pred_abl_pvi_done 1 or 0) is significant
2. Select only cases where pvi_abl_pvi_done = 1 (ie the procedure is done (90% of the trials), and exclude medical treatment), and THEN do a further multivariate regression where I include all the procedural questions.

Do you think I need to do these 2 analyses separately due to the correlation?

Comment: Not sure about the answer to your questions, but do you not need to use rma.mv to take account of the multiple arms per study? You do refer to it as a multivariate analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me answer the specific concern you have. It should be fine to use all of the data and include `pred_abl_pvi_done` and the variables that indicate the "extras" in the same model. Yes, `pred_abl_pvi_done` and the `pred_abl_*` variables will be highly correlated, but the coefficients you obtain indicate the "incremental" value of adding the extras on top of the procedure. If the extras don't add anything, the coefficients for the `pred_abl_*` variables will hover around 0 and any significant results will be due to chance.

Try out the following code:

```
library(metafor)

k <- 100

vi <- runif(k, .05, 1)
trt <- c(rep(0,k/2), rep(1,k/2))
ext <- sample(c(0,1), k, replace=TRUE) * trt
yi <- 0.5 * trt + rnorm(k, 0, .25) + rnorm(k, 0, sqrt(vi))

rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ trt + ext)
```

Variable `trt` indicates whether the treatment was performed or not and `ext` whether some kind of extra was added. The two variables are highly correlated. But in the true model, only `trt` exerts an influence on the observed outcomes (plus there is some heterogeneity and of course sampling error). If you run the code many times, you will see that `trt` is usually correctly identified as a significant predictor while `ext` is not.

Of course, if `ext` adds something that is not already accounted for by `trt`, then this should also start to show up in the results.

So, that part is fine as far as I am concerned. However, I am a bit more concerned about the fact that you are not accounting for the fact that the arm-level outcomes have a multilevel structure (@mdewey also hinted at this in the comments). Right now, you are treating the data essentially cross-sectionally, when I think you should really be looking at the influence of your predictors *within trials*.

To do so, you can either add `factor(id)` as a predictor (so, you add fixed study effects) or you could use random study effects with `rma.mv(..., random = ~ 1 | id/arm)`. There is a bit of a debate in the literature which of the two is more appropriate, but you could explore (and report) both approaches and hopefully the conclusions are consistent.

Comment: Any pointers to the literature to which you refer in last para?

Comment: You could start here: http://dij.sagepub.com/content/34/2/535.abstract

Comment: Many thanks! I've posted the results here: http://pastebin.com/8U67tKGU - I didn't seem to be able to get the second method working as you can see (even with "id/arm" as you wrote). Is it a fundamentally different function? It's not clear how to specify I want to use the proportional measure as I did with PLO in rma()...

Comment: You need to do ``af_dat <- escalc(measure="PLO", xi=xi, ni=ni, data=af_dat)`` and then ``rma.mv(yi, vi, ...)``. The ``rma.mv()`` function does not allow you to use ``measure`` and so on. So you need to do this in two steps.

Comment: Ah yes! I used rma.mv(xi, ni, ...) as opposed to yi, vi (I assumed that's what you expected?) and got this: http://pastebin.com/60t3n35G - interestingly fairly different results with much less impressive tests for significance...

Comment: EDIT: And I'f I do it with ...random = ~ 1 | id/arm) as you mentioned I lose all significance: http://pastebin.com/72gPtqPJ

Comment: You need to use ``escalc()``. ``rma.mv(xi, ni, ...)`` makes no sense.

Comment: I see, thanks! http://pastebin.com/7efEh7DA Very good :)

Comment: Could I just ask why we need the random study effects stratified by "id/arm" rather than just the "id" alone?

Comment: You want to account for study- and arm-level heterogeneity.

Comment: I am unsure why we might expect arm-level heterogeneity? The inclusion/exclusion criteria in these randomised trials mean the two groups should be similar? Sorry about the questions but I'm genuinely interested!

Comment: Sorry just to clarify, by the two groups I mean the arms within a study. If patients are randomised to each arm, surely there should be minimal heterogeneity between the arms?

Comment: The results you posted say otherwise - the arm-level variance component is (at least) as large as the study-level one.